# how to extract folder hierarchy from a path string that is stored in an xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, minidom

I have stored a string in **xml** as

```
< xml >
< path > /home/user/Desktop/Folder < / path >
```

Now, using python i want to extract all the paths from the string and store them in a list.

Example:
the list should contains all these paths:

```
home

home/user

home/user/Desktop

home/user/Desktop/Folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the string from the xml like this - (I've used [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html))

```
#importing ElementTree
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> xml_string = '''<xml><path>/home/user/Desktop/Folder</path></xml>'''
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
>>> s = root.find("path").text
>>> print s
/home/user/Desktop/Folder
```

After getting the string, you can parse it something like this -

```
#Logic for splitting the contents
>>> split_li = s.split("/")
>>> ["/".join(split_li[:i]) for i in range(2, len(split_li) + 1)]
['/home', '/home/user', '/home/user/Desktop', '/home/user/Desktop/Folder']
```